# Fourier transform (algebra involving expansion)

Tags: fourier-transform

How do you go from $$\sum_{0}^\infty (0.5e^-jw)^n$$

to

$$\frac{1}{1-0.5e^-jw}=\frac{e^jw}{e^jw-0.5}$$

and I was looking and this formula

$$\sum_{m=0}^{m=n} (a)^n = \frac{1-(a)^(n+1)}{1-a}$$

Comment: Thank you. I know it's a geomatric series but I am stuck with algebra. Need someone to show the work.

Comment: is the formula in the link the same as the one I am looking at?

Comment: Thank you. I got it